# linksys WAG120n DSL router MAC filtering

Tags: networking, mac, wireless-networking, router

i know very well what MAC address denotes to, what it is used for. i also know how to learn the MAC address of each PC connected to the router by checking them out on each computer. However, if its the case that i logged in to that router and went through
MAC filtering. On that section, i observed a few MAC addresses. How am i supposed to know which MAC address typed there belongs to which computer connected to the network 'without going to each computer' ?

Comment: Is there an "Attached devices" status screen that would list MAC address, IP address and host name?

Answer (score 0):

In your router settings,  (MAC address filtering), there must an option to add a name to each physical address. Add the name of your device corresponding to the MAC address you enter. If this option is not there, write it down on a piece of paper or save it in a notepad file on your PC by adding the MAC address and the corresponding name of the device. (Eg: laptop, desktop, smartphone, android tab etc..)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do that through the web interface of the router, that will very much depend on the firmware.  Most of the time, there will be a button on one of the configuration screens labeled something like "client table".  This will create a pop-up that lists all the devices connected along with their host names and MAC addresses.

The other option, if you only have wireless connections, is to look for the "Wireless clients table".  It's basically the same thing as the first one for only wireless connections, but I find this option is usually easier to find.